# width is not working at vertically rotated text's columns

Tags: css, rotatetransform, vertical-text

I'm trying to make vertical text at table column header. I've made it, Now, I want to make the vertical-text's column much more thinner as those columns contain numbers only. For that reason, I tried to decrease that column(th)'s width, but, it didn't work! How can I fix this?

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/G3wXm/1/)

Some Css:

```
table.myTable th.rotate-container {
    height: 80px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
table.myTable th.rotate-container > div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Sort of a nasty fix, tempted to search around to find a better one,  you could add something like `margin:0 -25px;` http://jsfiddle.net/G3wXm/2/

Comment: @user1896653 well, I have to say that it's really good if you know how to use it. Instead of setting the `width` for the column, you can just change the negative margin and the width of the inner div. However the `width` of the column should be set at some fixed minimum value (`1px` is the best). Then you adjust the negative margin and the width of the inner div. You have the inner div's width `80px`, the negative margin (left and right) is `-25px`, so you have the actual width as `80 - 25 * 2 = 30px`, so if you want to change the col width to 50px, just set `-15px` for negative margin.